# How to use Comparable<T>?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following `interface`

```
public interface Identifiable {

    public Comparable<?> getIdentifier();

}
```

And an implementing class

```
public class Agreement implements Identifiable {

    private Long id;

    public Comparable<Long> getIdentifier() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Note that there may be other implementations with different types of identifiers.
Now I would like to, yes, compare the comparables:

```
// Agreement a;
// Agreement b;
...
if (a.getIdentifier().compareTo(b.getIdentifier()) {
...
```

But the `compareTo` gives me the following compiler error:

*The method compareTo(Long) in the type Comparable<Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable<Long>)*

How is this interface supposed to be used with Generics?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Comparable<T>` is meant to be used as an upper bound for a generic parameter:

```
public interface Identifiable<T extends Comparable<T>> {    
    public T getIdentifier();
}

public class Agreement implements Identifiable<Long> {

    private final Long id;

    public Long getIdentifier() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

This forces the return type to be a `T`, not just something that can be compared to a `T`.

---

Your code is inherently unsafe.
To understand why, consider the following code:

```
class Funny implements Comparable<Long> { ... }
class Funnier implements Identifiable {
    public Comparable<Long> getIdentifier() {
        return new Funny();
    }
}

Identifiable<Funny> funnier;
funnier.getIdentifier().compareTo(funnier.getIdentifier());
// You just tried to pass a Funny to compareTo(Long)
```

Comment: Your example opened my eyes. Thank you!

Comment: I think the bound here is not "lower" but upper, am I right ?

Comment: @Mulmoth The first time I saw `<T extends Comparable<T>>` my eyes were pretty wide too. ;)

Comment: But what if I have several methods like `getIdentifier`, maybe with different types. Isn't it possible to use it more in the "raw" way without stating the return type of a method within the class' diamond operator?

Comment: @Mulmoth You can do this with raw `Comparable` with warnings you can suppress.

Comment: ... and it wouldn't be any prettier. ;)

Comment: @Mulmoth: No.  More advanced type systems (monads) can do this safely, by defining Comparable to take the type of the implementing class.

Comment: for best results, use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`